# How to share a photos with facebook and twitter?

Tags: iphone, three20, share, photo-gallery

I have created a photo gallery application using Three20 framework. It works fine with previous, next and play button in toolbar. But i want include a button for sharing the photos with facebook and twitter.

How to make this?

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single point of sharing, I think [`ShareKit`](http://getsharekit.com/) is a great utility. You can easily extend the sharing feature to more than just Facebook and Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use IOS sdk from facebook here the link: [Facebook for iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the Following.

1-Facebook ApI
2-Twitter ApI

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the [Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) from github and made a custom view controller based on their sample. To post a photo, I used this code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               image, @"picture",
                               nil];

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                      andParams:params
                  andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                    andDelegate:self];
```

where the `facebook` object is an instance of `FacebookService` provided in the Facebook SDK and `image` is a `UIImage`. However it's a lot more complicated than this because first you have to go to the Facebook developers site and register your app to get an App ID and Access Token, then in your app will you have to have the user autheticate your app with Facebook and handle errors, etc. You can figure it all out from their sample code in the SDK.

I haven't tried Twitter yet.

Answer (score 0):

BMSocialShare should get you going.

https://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare